# Type cast address in C

Tags: c, casting, structure

```
typedef struct iomFixedPIA 
{
    UINT16      state;  /* State    */
    UINT16      modStatus;/* Module status*/
} IOM_FIXED_PIA;

#define IOM_PIA_SIZE 256 /* Size of PIA per IO module */

typedef char CM_IOM_PIA [IOM_PIA_SIZE]; /* PIA for one module */

printf("Actual PIA address from PIA offset = %x  modid: %d and pPIA: %x \n",
       CI856_CM_ADRS(CI856_PIA_OFFSET), pParMsg->modId,
       ((CI856_CM_ADRS(CI856_PIA_OFFSET)) + pParMsg->modId) );

pMod->pPIA = (IOM_FIXED_PIA *)
             ((CM_IOM_PIA *) (CI856_CM_ADRS(CI856_PIA_OFFSET)) + pParMsg->modId);
// question here ^^

printf(" pMod PIA= %x  \n", pMod->pPIA);
```

If I running above code I am getting output as below.

```
Actual PIA addres from PIA offset = 300051c modid: 1 and pPIA: 300051d
pMod PIA= 300061c and POA= 3007020
```

My question is.

1. When we do type caste to type  (CM_IOM_PIA *) above why we are seeing value of 300061c  instead of 300051d?
2. Why there is no change in address if we do typecast to (IOM_FIXED_PIA *) after we type cast (CM_IOM_PIA *)?
3. In general if we do type cast does we have change in address?

Comment: Is this statement correct: `typedef char CM_IOM_PIA [IOM_PIA_SIZE];`. I mean can one`typedef` `char` type to an array type?

Comment: @nishant: Yes, it is. This defines `CM_IOM_PIA` to be synonymous to a `char` array of length `IOM_PIA_SIZE`.

Comment: You might like to read about pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, type casting doesn't change the adress of your variable, it changes how the computer will interprete your variable. The adress doesn't change because, your variable can be on 8bits, 32 or 64bits it always start at the same adress. But if you have an array and cast it in a differente type, when you'll interate on it your program will itererate on a smallest size, ex :

```
char*    array;
int*     i;

array = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
i = (int*)array;
```

you will have 4 * 8bits, so you'll have 32bits, which can be cast as int but if you iterate on your int-array you'll go out of memory because the program will walk by sizeof(int) so you'll exceed your memory allocation.

I hope I helped you.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef char CM_IOM_PIA [IOM_PIA_SIZE];
```

Is a pointer to char of 256 bytes 
In C when you add one to a pointer it grow by the size of the pointer data. If it was 32 bit integer data pointer+1 point to the next integer so pointer advance of 4 bytes. In your specific case as the structure size is 256 bytes the pointer move of 256 bytes each time you add 1.

```
(CM_IOM_PIA *) is a 256 char pointer so (CM_IOM_PIA *) +1 point to your address + 256 => 300061c
```

It's only a problem of operator precedence the cast is made before the addition so it grow by 256 instead of 1. The simple fix if to add parenthesis around `(CI856_CM_ADRS(CI856_PIA_OFFSET)) + pParMsg->modId` to do the mathemathical operation before the cast.

Comment: can you please eloborate. I didn't get this

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the missing braces in

```
(CI856_CM_ADRS(CI856_PIA_OFFSET)) + pParMsg->modId);
```

typecast after addition.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *foo = NULL;
int *bar = NULL;
printf("%p %p\n", foo+1, bar+1);
```

will output 1 and 4 (likely, assuming sizeof(int) == 4). Address math using sizeof of original types.

Comment: Both your answer and Hulor's should be merged.

Answer (score 0):

To get the same addreses in both `printf()`s should instead of doing:

```
pMod->pPIA = (IOM_FIXED_PIA *)
         ((CM_IOM_PIA *) (CI856_CM_ADRS(CI856_PIA_OFFSET)) + pParMsg->modId);
```

do:

```
pMod->pPIA = (IOM_FIXED_PIA *)
         ((CM_IOM_PIA *) ((CI856_CM_ADRS(CI856_PIA_OFFSET)) + pParMsg->modId));
```

in the second `printf()`.

So the addtion `+ pParMsg->modId` would be done based on the type of `(CI856_CM_ADRS(CI856_PIA_OFFSET))` as apposed to the OP where it is done based on the type `CM_IOM_PIA`.